# Elastic Integrations as a YAML

Tags: elasticsearch, ansible, infrastructure-as-code

I am trying to create "automated" Elastic deployment.

I am using Ansible - I've created Ansible roles for building Elasticsearch and Kibana, and now I want to proceed with integrations.

And now comes the hard part: I am able to create Fleet policy following Elastic guidelines from [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/fleet/8.6/create-a-policy-no-ui.html), but I am not able to find any sources, that would guide me with the next steps.

Here's how I create *Fleet policy* in the *kibana.yml* file:

```
[...]
# =================== Fleet Config ====================
xpack.fleet.packages:
  - name: fleet_server
    version: latest
xpack.fleet.agentPolicies:
  - name: Fleet Server policy (IaC)
    id: fleet-server-policy
    namespace: default
    package_policies:
      - name: fleet_server-1
        package:
          name: fleet_server
[...]
```

After I create this policy, I should configure Fleet Server, Elastic Agents and some integrations. Unfortunately I am not able to find any sources on how am I supposed to do that "programmatically" or with YAML configs. Or maybe I have a misconception of how it should be done, and it shouldn't be automated?

There was a discussion on Elastic's Github quite a while ago: https://github.com/elastic/kibana/issues/88956 but I haven't found any related documentation on Elastic's website.

I would be grateful for any guidance :)